# Should (May) a user himself delete a downvoted question?

Tags: discussion, support, downvoted-questions

This question arose in the context of [I am in "danger of being blocked from asking any more", but I didn't do any bad](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9576/i-am-in-danger-of-being-blocked-from-asking-any-more-but-i-didnt-do-any-bad/9577?noredirect=1#comment25967_9577)

But it is relevant to any stackexchange site.

What should a user do with a question that has a net negative score (sorry, I don't think *score* is the technical term), and it is not possible to edit it into better shape? In other words, what is recommended that the user do if he comes to realize it was not a well-posed question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's truly an unsalvageable question, then yes, go ahead and delete it. The system allows you to delete your own questions if their score is zero or negative and they have at most one answer, which itself must have zero or lower score. (And score is in fact the technical term we use.)

But it's preferable to edit the question into shape if you can do so without completely changing the nature of the question.

Comment: In the context: what does it mean for a user if he does that?

Comment: You mean delete your post? Well, deleted posts do count toward automatic question blocks, so if you delete a _lot_ of posts, you could find yourself unable to ask questions. But if you delete just an occasional post, there are no consequences.

Comment: @DavidZ Are you saying that if the question does not have an answer, or if the answer does not have a negative score, the user won't be able to delete the question?

Comment: @aparente001 that's the opposite of what I said

Comment: @DavidZ Oh, I see, the question may not have *more than one answer*.  Are there any other situations in which the user may not delete his question?

Comment: I'd suggest checking the FAQ on that - it's one of the links in the sidebar. (can't link right now, I'm on a phone)

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks for the suggestion -- I confess I had not found that before.  I went there, did a search on page for the likely suspects, and didn't find anything relevant, unfortunately.  If you come across some specific links, great -- but take your time.

Comment: Top link in the sidebar, search for "deleted" and click the link, then the [first answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/56541) gives you all the information you should need.